# Kafka PointToPoint

Tags: java, jms, apache-kafka

**The Problem**

We have a multi-datacenter activeMQ setup, with NFS for each HA pair, and it seems that activeMQ isn't really scalable, and doesn't play well with NFS issues. (we're using 5.7)

**The Possible Solution**

Move to Kafka

**Requirements**

- We need PointToPoint & pub/sub functionality
- Message Priorities (I know kafka doesn't provide that out of the box, but there's a workaround for it on our side)

**Question**

Is this possible with Kafka (not necessarily out-of-the-box, but with some client tweaking)? If not, then what other technology would you suggest? It doesn't have to be JMS, but it needs to be scalable and reliable (and it needs to play well with NFS)

Answer (score 1):

> We need PointToPoint & pub/sub functionality

Kafka does that, shared my finding [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18501545/simple-pull-message-queue/18514164#18514164)

> Message Priorities

Little confused what exactly you mean, but by priorities if you mean to consume from a specific offset then the Low level or Simple consumer API provide that. It also supports re-submission of messages as well

Answer (score 0):

For point to point delivery of messages, (single producer, single consumer), you can configure the number of partitions as 1. Producer will publish messages on this topic and partition and a single consumer, will read from that topic and partition. A topic would equate to your queue in ActiveMQ terms.

If you want to add message priorities, I would use the lower level Kafka client, you could then increase the number of partitions, (each partition for a message of different priority level), and have the consumer fetch messages from the highest priority topic first, if  no message exists it would then fetch from the next lower priority topic.

Comment: They can use separate topic for each priority level

Answer (score 0):

In your case I would use Kafka with 1 partition per topic with separate topics for each message priority level, solving prioritization of delivery on the subscriber side.

Answer (score 0):

Kafka provides point to point and publish subscribe usage patterns by **user groups** concept. 
What there is not directly supported is selectors, priorities. But you get possibility tho distribute messages across partitions so you could for example distribute messages based on priority to partitions. 
You also get for free message persistence (one of the core principles) limited by retention policy. Each message in kafka is essentially key-value pair. Key has some specific semantics in partitioning and log compaction. There is nothing like in traditional messaging systems that you can use custom header which you can use for routing etc. Following [article](http://jakubstransky.com/2016/11/02/introduction-to-apache-kafka-destilled/) tries to summarize that.